# Decentralized Ticketing and Wiki System

Tags: git

I am working with a team in a country with a very bad internet connection.

Currently we are coordinating via email and text files in a SVN.

But this is not optimal.

Are there any project management systems that are based on git?

I found ticgit as a ticket system based on GIT and it would be nice to have a similar solution for displaying markdown files in a wiki structure.

Comment: GitHub's [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) is very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- TicGit as a Ticketing System
- GitIt as a Wiki System